# Select few columns from Model and select few columns from its relation table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

**User Model**

```
class UserModel extends Authenticatable
{

    use Notifiable;

    public $table = 'tbluser';
    public $primaryKey = 'UserID';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function Role() {
        return $this->hasOne("\App\Models\User\Role\RoleModel", "RoleID", "RoleID");
    }
}
```

**Role Model**

```
class RoleModel extends Model
{
    public $table = 'tblrole';
    public $primaryKey = 'RoleID';
    public $timestamps = false;        
}
```

My code is below which gets all columns from both tables. Below code shows all columns from user table and all columns from relational table - role

```
$data = UserModel::with("Role")->get();
```

I tried below code to select few columns from both table.

```
$data = UserModel
    ::select("UserName", "EmailAddress", "LastName")
    ->with(['Role' => function ($q) {
               $q->select('Role')
            }])
    ->get();
```

but did not work. It shows three columns as expected from user table but no info from role table for associated record.

Anything missing?

Comment: Is the key on the `role` table actually named `RoleID`?

Comment: Yes. It is RoleID. If you want, I could send schema.

Comment: So you have a table roles, with a primary key of `RoleID` as opposed to `id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `with` call you need to select the primary key from your `Role` model so the roles will get attached when they are retrieved after the query. Besides that, select whatever other columns you want in the closure passed to the `with` method:

```
$data = UserModel::select("UserName", "EmailAddress", "LastName")
    ->with(['Role' => function ($q) {
               $q->select('RoleID', 'Role', 'OtherColumn')
            }])
    ->get();
```

Then you can access a user and roles with:

```
// This will return the first user
$user = $data->first();

// This returns the entire user role model with the selected columns
$role = $user->Role;

// Access Role attributes through the Role Model
$role->Role;
```

Comment: I selected the RoleID column also in the with call, but still the relation is always null for each user record.

Comment: One more important point...your code works only if I remove select statement and fetch all User Columns.

Comment: You'd have to add `"RoleID"` to the `UserModel` select so the role can be attached to the corresponding user after the queries are run.

Comment: Perfect. +1. Accepted. Bounty is urs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this :

```
$data = UserModel
    ::select("UserName", "EmailAddress", "LastName")
    ->with(['tblrole' => function ($q) {
               $q->select('Role')
            }])
    ->get();
```

**OR**

```
$data = DB::table('tblrole')->select('tblrole.*','tbluser.UserName','tbluser.EmailAddress','tbluser.LastName')
        ->join('tbluser','tbluser.id','=','tblrole.user_id')
        ->get();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: First part is same as I wrote in my question. Did I miss anything? It doesn't work.'

Answer (score 0):

In your select(....) of **with** add foreign key of tblRole table related to Primary key of tblUser table.
And then list of all other column that you wants to fetch.

```
$data = UserModel
        ::select("UserName", "EmailAddress", "LastName")
        ->with(['Role' => function ($q) {
                   $q->select('RoleID', 'Role')
                }])
        ->get();
```